# Set TabView color on active tab selection and on load

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am building my `TabView` and I can't seem to come across this answer anywhere, so I wanted to see if someone might be able to help me.

So I have the following code:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @State var activeTab = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
                MapView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Explore", systemImage: "location.magnifyingglass")
                            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                ListView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                FavoritesView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Favorite", systemImage: "heart")
                            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                    }
                    .tag(2)
                ProfileView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Profile", systemImage: "person")
                            .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                    }
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .onChange(of: activeTab, perform: { value in
                print("User has selected tab: \(value)")
            })
        }
        .onAppear() {
            mainViewModel.fetchPlaces()
        }
    } //: body
} //: MainView
```

Which produces the following look:

[image]

How do I change the color of the icon and text when it's on active state? I want to utilize `Color("ColorGreen")`, but I can't seem to figure it out as if I set `.foregroundcolor` on any element, it throws errors.

When the app loads, it lands on `.tab(0)` by default, so I'd like to have it be automatically colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the tab view uses your app's accent colour, which is also used by prominent buttons, navigation bar buttons, etc.. So if you want to use your custom shade of green for *all* of those, you can set the colour named **AccentColor** in your assets.

If you want to use a custom colour just for the tab view icons, and you want each of the icons to be the same colour when selected, you can apply the `.tint()` modifier to your `TabView`:

```swift
TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
  // list of tab views and tabItem modifiers
}
.tint(Color("CustomGreen"))
```

If you want to use a different custom colour for one specific tab icon, you can adjust the tint based on the value of `activeTab`:

```swift
TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
  // list of tab views and tabItem modifiers
}
.tint(activeTab == 0 ? Color("CustomGreen") : .accentColor)
```

I would say that setting an app's accent colour and using it every everywhere is probably safest in terms of user experience, compared to overriding it. Being consistent with your use of colour makes your app instantly more consistent with standard app usage, so it means that the way your user selects information and navigation doesn't contain any surprises. This allows them to concentrate on the real value of your app. But if you need to alter colours in a contextual way, it is possible using the methods above.

Comment: Thanks @ScottM, this worked out perfectly - I utilized the .accentColor because it definitely makes more sense to use that, much appreciated for the explanation.